# gradle NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)

Tags: log4j, gradle, velocity, slf4j, nosuchmethoderror

(My second Gradle problem...)

I'm trying to setup a call to Velocity in one of my tasks. Velocity does a direct call to log4j which Gradle somehow seems to divert to its log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.2.jar, causing a NoSuchMethodError.

So I have:

```
buildscript  {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.apache.velocity:velocity:1.7'
        // ... asumes provided:
        classpath 'log4j:log4j:1.2.12'
    }
}
```

And then later in a task I do...

```
def template = Velocity.getTemplate('src\\jnlp\\jnlpTemplate.vm')
```

This raises an exception. And the last part of the stacktrace is

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute.initAppender(Log4JLogChute.java:117)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute.init(Log4JLogChute.java:85)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.LogManager.createLogChute(LogManager.java:157)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.LogManager.updateLog(LogManager.java:269)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.initializeLog(RuntimeInstance.java:871)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:262)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.requireInitialization(RuntimeInstance.java:302)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1531)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1514)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeSingleton.getTemplate(RuntimeSingleton.java:299)
        at org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity.getTemplate(Velocity.java:358)
        at org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity$getTemplate.call(Unknown Source)
        at build_49a099islbrnod06rkiudfavms$_run_closure1.doCall(C:\home\...\build.gradle:67)
```

My analysis so far is as follows:

The constructor PatternLayout(String), that is called by Velocity is part of log4j's PatternLayout class, but it seems Gradle ends up resolving PatternLayout to a class in $GRADLE_HOME/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.2.jar. And that jar's PatternLayout seems to be a very minimal implementation lacking the requested constructor.

Is there some workaround here? Did I make some beginners mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the log4j jar from your app: the bridge log4j-over-slf4j and the log4j have the same methods, with the same signature (there could be some issues caused by different loading order into the classpath). If you want to use the bridge you don't need the log4j lib, you have to choose another logging framework which implements slf4j (for example log-back).

It could be a version issue. The version 1.7.2 of the bridge could be too high, try to downgrade to a lower version.

Comment: (2nd attempt to add a comment.)

I've added the log4j dependency because that's what velocity wants. Its velocity that calls the method that is in log4j but not in de bridge log4j-over-sl4j. If I remove the log4j dependency then velocity still wants to call the method, which is still not in the bridge jar.

The problem seems to be that a "full" log4j and the "bridge" do not have the same methods. Specifally its the PatternLayout(String) constructor that is missing from the latter.